# What is a more efficient way to run this simple task in Py3?

Tags: python, dictionary, if-statement

TempAvg recordings for the day in 5min intervals are extracted from a dictionary as defined in the variables below.
I am trying to run a program that records when tempAvg reduces by 1 or more in the subsequent recorded tempAvg.
There must be a simpler way to run this rather than writing lines and lines of code as there are 288 tempAvg recordings/day.
I sense this might be trivial, so i apologise i am new but very open to learning :) Thanks

```
temp1 = response['observations'][0]['metric']['tempAvg']   
temp2 = response['observations'][1]['metric']['tempAvg']
temp3 = response['observations'][2]['metric']['tempAvg']
temp4 = response['observations'][3]['metric']['tempAvg'].  
if (temp1 - temp2) >= 1:
   print(temp1 - temp2)
if (temp2 - temp3) >= 1:
   print(temp2 - temp3)
if (temp3 - temp4) >= 1:
   print(temp3 - temp4)`
```

...etc

Comment: OIbviously one would use a loop. However, if the temperature is a floatting point, you probably won't get many sudden drops of 1 degree... and if it is integer you have the possibility that sometime the temperature might oscillate between 2 values. Thus in practice, that code might not be appropriate.  For exemple, what if the temperature drops 0.5 degree twice in a row?

Comment: @GinoMempin apologies have updated!

Comment: @Phil1970 great point. I am thankfully only interested in single temperature drops in a 5 minute interval. Thanks

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Please try below code.

```
n = 288
for index in range(1, n):
    previous = index - 1
    temp1 = response['observations'][previous]['metric']['tempAvg']
    temp2 = response['observations'][index]['metric']['tempAvg']
    delta = temp1 - temp2
    if delta >= 1:
        print(delta)
```

Regards,

Hamid